# smbclient doesn't show folder permission of server?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

When I connect to Windows server using `smbclient` from Linux as below:

```
smbclient //SERVER/FOLDER -U user%password
```

This connects to the server successfully but when I use stat command on a particular folder it throws errors:

```
smb: > stat folder 
Server doesn't support UNIX CIFS calls.
```

Is there any way to get folder permissions of a Windows share on Linux using samba?

Answer (score 6):

Windows permissions are usually governed by an ACL, which is not displayed by `smbclient`.  Instead, try `smbcacls //SERVER/SHARE FILENAME -U user%password`.  You should get something like:

```
REVISION:1
CONTROL:SR|PD|DI|DP
OWNER:NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
GROUP:NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
ACL:NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL
ACL:BUILTIN\Administrators:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL
ACL:LAPTOP-CD837F\localuser:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL
ACL:Everyone:ALLOWED/OI|CI/READ
```

Comment: This answer solved my issue, I was trying to fix for 5 days. Thanks